# Custom camera animation on Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

Is it possible to define custom camera animation on google maps in Android? This perhaps boils down to being able to create custom CameraUpdateFactory methods that interact with the animateCamera interpolator, etc. -- or just pass a custom animation.

The simplest thing I want to do is animate the camera at constant speed through multiple points. Say I have an array of LatLng, I want to accelerate once (perhaps zoom too), move at constant speed through all of the intermediate points, and decelerate at the last point (and perhaps reset zoom). Using map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(..)) has the unfortunate effect of zooming in/out and accelerate/decelerating at each point.

This seems too simple to not be supported out-of-the-box (both array or list of LatLng and being able to extend the camera animation functionality).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly you can't have that functionality right now.

Chaining camera positions will look fine for some cases (see [lines 80-100 here](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-v2-demo/blob/master/NewMapsDemo/src/pl/mg6/newmaps/demo/AnimateCameraChainingExampleActivity.java)), but I guess not in your case.

One thing I can suggest is positng a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

Comment: update your code by adding <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> otherwise it is not showing map. And remove the old permission

Comment: @Nepster The code should work fine if imported into Eclipse. I don't use Eclipse for over a year now and I don't think it's worth updating the project with gradle and the latest Google Play Services lib version. Note the repository contains Google Play Services 3.x, which didn't use `google_play_services_version` at all.